# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code which is not working for me.

```
  dir('anyName'){
    checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: PIPELINE_VERSION]],
      userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'some-id', url: 'some git repo']]
    ]
  }

  def some = load "./pipelines/environment/some.groovy"
```

But I get the following error. How can I load a file and later use its internal function.

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
> /mnt/data/jenkins/workspace//pipelines/environment/some.groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [dir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) step documentation:

> Change current directory. Any step inside the dir block will use this directory as current and any relative path will use it as base path.

The `dir` command changes the base directory only for code executed inside the `dir {}` block, therefore when you load your file after the `dir` block you are back to the original workspace and the file is not found.
to solve it you can use the full path to load the file:

```
dir('anyName'){
    checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: PIPELINE_VERSION]],
                   userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'some-id', url: 'some git repo']]
    ]
}
// From here we are back to the default workspace
def some = load "./anyName/pipelines/environment/some.groovy"
```

Or alternatively load the file inside the `dir` block:

```
dir('anyName'){
    checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: PIPELINE_VERSION]],
                   userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'some-id', url: 'some git repo']]
    ]
    def some = load "./pipelines/environment/some.groovy"
}
```

Comment: I tried the second one since I already tried the first. gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the groovy file is located at path `pipelines/environment/some.groovy` inside the main repository folder? also try to load without the `./`:  `def some = load "pipelines/environment/some.groovy"`